# Returning HTTP 204 vs. {"d":null} for non-returning ASP.Net script services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, pagemethods

We've got an ASP.Net web method that returns no data, that is, it's not supposed to return any data, the method is a void. Currently the response is a status 200 w/a body of {"d":null}. While that works fine it bothers me that it's not a response status of 204 (No Content) and no body. Anyone know of a way to get the web method to return a 204 if there's no body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, was being lazy when I posted. Spent some time in JustDecompile and the answer seems to be "no." Specifically the webmethod is invoked from w/in the framework (System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod) as:

```
object obj1 = methodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(obj, rawParams);
        string str1 = null;
        if (!methodData.UseXmlResponse)
        {
            str1 = string.Concat("{\"d\":", methodData.Owner.Serializer.Serialize(obj1), "}");
            str = "application/json";
        }
```

So obj1 will be null if it's a void method, but that doesn't matter, it's still serialized with the leading "d:" stuff. No way to avoid it. Oh well, like I said in the quesiton it works fine that way, was just hoping for the 204 since there's no "real" response.